# Perl HTTP request skips proxy server and connects to target directly

Tags: perl, http, http-proxy

I'm trying to write a perl script to pull data from a web address through a Squid proxy server. I have Squid server running on CentOS7, listening on port 3128 and authenticating with `/usr/lib64/squid/basic_ncsa_auth`. However, I keep getting perl seems to bypass the proxy entirely and connects to the target directly.

I was able to do this through curl but not with perl.

I have rewritten my perl script several ways. I've updated perl versions (currently on 5.28).

```
use LWP::UserAgent;

$ENV{'HTTP_PROXY'} = 'http://localhost:3128/';
$ENV{'HTTP_PROXY_USERNAME'} = 'user1';
$ENV{'HTTP_PROXY_PASSWORD'} = 'password1';

$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();

$ua->proxy('http', 'http://localhost:3128/');

my $req = HTTP::Request->new('GET', 'https://stackoverflow.com');

$req->proxy_authorization_basic("user1", "password1");
my $res = $ua->request($req);

print $res->code ."\n";
```

So, the above code produces a '200' however, I see no entry in my squid access logs. When I attempt the maneuver in curl

`curl --proxy-user user1:password1 -x http://localhost:3128 https://stackoverflow.com)`

I get

`1560893906.291    513 ::1 TCP_TUNNEL/200 270148 CONNECT stackoverflow.com:443 user1 HIER_DIRECT/151.101.65.69 -`

in the access log.

Obviously, there's some step that I'm missing, but I've copied examples from the perl documentation and was unable to get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ua->proxy('http', 'http://localhost:3128/');
my $req = HTTP::Request->new('GET', 'https://stackoverflow.com');
```

Given that you access a `https://`  URL you need to set the proxy for the protocol `https`, not `http` as you did.

```
$ENV{'HTTP_PROXY'} = 'http://localhost:3128/';
```

This setting is only used if you explicitly enable proxy setting by environment, i.e. `$ua->env_proxy`. Moreover the setting should be for `HTTPS_PROXY` not `HTTP_PROXY` here too.

Comment: So, to be clear, are you saying the proxy itself needs to be configured for SSL, or the protocol in the just needs to be changed in the proxy declaration? If i just change the proxy declaration to 

         `$ua->proxy('https', 'http://localhost:3128/'); `

I get a 500 back and see
       `1560959645.942 0 ::1 TCP_DENIED/407 4127 CONNECT stackoverflow.com:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html`

in the logs.

An earlier version I had written was printing out `500 establishing SSL tunnel failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required`  but I don't remember how I got that to print out.

Comment: @DougieO: The line you cite shows a 407 response from the proxy, i.e. authentication required for the proxy. To specify credentials for the proxy use `http://user:pass@localhost:3128/` syntax.